# Use https instead of http in urls in templates for static files

Tags: ssl, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Currently we are using the default wirecloud template. But sinde we enabled SSL and redirect every request to the ssl port I would love to change the urls of static ressources to start with https to avoid mixed content warnings.

Is there a simple way to change the urls to always start wit hhttps instead of http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done automatically, except if WireCloud is behind a proxy (so requests comes using HTTP instead of HTTPS). In those cases you can force WireCloud to use https links by adding this line into the `settings.py` file:

```py
FORCE_PROTO = "https"
```

See this [link](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installation_guide/#force_proto) for more info.